# Можно ли менять сообщения комитов при клонировании репозитория в Git?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Мне нужно клонировать старый SVN репозиторий в новый Git репозиторий. Процесс описывать не нужно, все уже сделано, да и информации в сети много. Но один вопрос остался не ясным. Я знаю как при клонировании исправить информацию о пользователях, например добавить актуальную почту. При миграции в Git все комиты создаются с нуля. Можно ли как-то вклиниться в этот процесс, хуком или еще чем, и присоединить номера ревизий SVN к коментариям, ну или просто заменить комментарии на номера ревизий и как это сделать?

Хотелось бы сделать именно во время клонирования, т.к. существующие способы исправления комментариев по живому Git-репозиторию подходят только для единичных случаев, и то требуют осторожности.

Гуглом ничего путного найти не удалось ни на русском (и не рассчитывал), ни на английском. Документацию читал, но может проглядел, если так ткните носом в нужное место.

Comment: [просто не используйте опцию `--no-metadata` команды `git svn clone`, и в сообщение будет добавлена информация вида `git-svn-id: svn://svn.domain.tld/repo/project/trunk@19815 e13dc095-444b-fa4e-8f24-06838a8318a5`.](https://habrahabr.ru/post/144626/)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin эту статью я как-то пропустил, спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте зайти с другой стороны - измените комментарии в SVN. Это легко и описано во множестве источников, в том числе, на русском.

Comment: ну мы собственно к этому решению в итоге и пришли, но все равно спасибо.